# Python Geocoder w3w

Tags: python, geocoding, what3words

I am trying to use w3w API with this python geocoder correctly. http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/index.html

It works fine when I use it with google and bing maps

```
import geocoder
g=geocoder.google('Oakhurst NJ')
geo=g.latlng
print geo
```

I have tried using what3words or w3w in a few different ways but I cannot get it working properly

1.

```
import geocoder
g=geocoder.w3w('Oakhurst.NJ.07755')
```

2.

```
import geocoder
g=geocoder.w3w('Oakhurst.NJ.07755', 'mykey')
```

3.

```
import geocoder    
w3w = what3words(apikey='mykey')
g=geocoder.w3w('Oakhurst.NJ.07755')
```

it keeps giving this name error:

NameError: name 'what3words' is not defined

do I have to download a library or module for what3words to work? not sure what I am doing wrong here

I have also seen this page that someone will probably refer me to https://github.com/what3words/w3w-python-wrapper but i still have had no luck.

Comment: Oakhurst.NJ.07755 looks more like an address, not a "3-word lookup'. Have you tried 3 real words, like `embedded.fizzled.trial`

Comment: i do not think that is the problem because the error it throws everytime is for    name 'what3words' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a couple of things going on here.

Firstly you need to have a valid what3words API key and either define this as an environment variable called `W3W_API_KEY` or pass it as the "key" parameter.

Secondly, `what3words` isn't defined as a module by the geocoder, it's the `w3w` method on the geocoder module that you'll need to invoke.

Finally, what3words is a forward geocoder for 3 word addresses, such as `index.home.raft` and a reverse geocoder from coordinates to 3 word addresses. what3words doesn't understand or know about street address components and even though your example uses *Oakhurst.NJ.07755* as a 3 word address, it's not a valid one (as [KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1419/khibma) correctly mentions); all 3 word addresses must have 3 words (naturally!) and each word must be be 4 alphabetic characters or more.

Putting all of this together and with an API key defined as an environment variable, this works on my machine.

```
$ pip install geocoder
$ export W3W_API_KEY=XXXXXX
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>> import geocoder
>> g = geocoder.w3w('index.home.raft)
>> g.json
{'status': 'OK', 'ok': True, 'language': u'en', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'status_code': 200, 'location': 'index.home.raft', 'words': [u'index', u'home', u'raft'], 'provider': 'w3w', 'lat': 51.521251, 'lng': -0.203586, 'type': u'3 words'}
>>> g = geocoder.w3w([51.521251,-0.203586], method='reverse')
>>> g.json
{'status': 'OK', 'ok': True, 'language': u'en', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'status_code': 200, 'location': '51.521251, -0.203586', 'words': [u'index', u'home', u'raft'], 'provider': 'w3w', 'lat': 51.521251, 'lng': -0.203586}
```

(disclaimer - I work for what3words)

Comment: wow your literally the perfect person to answer this question. So I used your exact code but used my API and it still did not work. I am new to using API's so bear with me here. I have my api key lets say it is 1N8UI. when define it as an environment variable should it be W3W_API_KEY='1N8UI' or should it include the API url https://api.what3words.com/w3w  ?

Comment: If you're using a Mac or Linux machine just exporting the key as an environment variable will work just fine, along the lines of `export W3W_API_KEY=XXXXX` - no need for API URLs.

Also, check that you have copied down your API key correctly and try an API call in your browser at this URL: http://api.what3words.com/w3w?string=plan.clips.above&key=XXXXX&lang=en replacing the XXXXX with your own API key.

Finally, when you say "it still did not work", what error message, if any, did you get?

Comment: i got windows..

Comment: If you're on Windows try `SET W3W_API_KEY=XXXX` from the command prompt

Comment: okay i set it, ran python from the command prompt followed your code and still nothing. I am on the what3words website and it is telling me I have a API key. should i email the technical support team?

Comment: Did you try this call to the API in your browser? 

http://api.what3words.com/w3w?string=plan.clips.above&key=XXXXX&lang=en

If that's not working or you still have problems please drop support@what3words.com a mail and we'll take a look for you tomorrow

Comment: yeah il email you guys tomorrow i got this: {"error":"X1","message":"Missing or invalid key"}

Comment: Great - please mention this post when you mail and I'll look out for it.

Comment: [ziggy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/63929/ziggy) - Haven't seen any support emails from you - if you've solved your issue could you please accept my answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hey sorry Gary I was really busy yesterday I will send a support email shortly